# How to run a node script automatically at specified intervals

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm making a dating app. Every day at midnight I want 'new matches' to be randomly found and displayed to a user.

If anyone could give a give high level overview of how this would work I'd be really grateful?

Comment: write the logic that you want to happen then setup a cron job that runs it every day at midnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to execute a Node task every midnight then Cron jobs is a powerful, yet simple tool that can help us get there. You can user [Cron Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to achieve this in node.

You can add cron dependency using

`npm install cron`

You can modify following script

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 00 01 * * *', function() {
  console.log('You see this message every day 01 AM America/Los_Angeles');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Where you can replace console.log with the logic you want to implement the code that will find match for each users of app and replace timezone with yours.